# How can I create a google proto message file from C++ program?

Tags: c++, c++11, protocol-buffers

I have an input file in xml which I have parsed and filled in my data structures using C++.

I am new to google protocol buffer, and I am not able to figure out how can I create a message (.prot) file from my filled in data structures.

Thanks

Comment: Start with https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial

Comment: THanks, I already went through that. All I see there is to write our own message files, and then using message file generating code. Using that code then to process further. After reading through the tutorial I notice that message file has to be created by ourselves manually? I could not find a way to automatically generate the message file from my c++ code !

Comment: @k2ibegin _"I could not find a way to automatically generate the message file from my c++ code !"_ That's not the way google protobuf works. You have to provide  a `.proto` file in first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to generate google protocol buffer `.proto` files from structure/class definitions in your C++ header files you would need to use some form of C++ reflection.

C++ does not have built-in reflection as of now, however, there are 3rd-party libraries that solve it.

With Boost Fusion [BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/define_struct.html) you can define your classes in such a way, that you can iterate over members at compile or run time. This solution is intrusive because it requires you to define structures using that macro, but it does not require any extra tools to be integrated into your build system.

Another option is to use a stand-alone code generator. One example is [Classdesc](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/2201).

Answer (score 1):

Protocol buffers are more of a replacement for XML than something you create with XML.
So in this case you would write your .proto files, to define your data model, then compile those into your .cpp files with the associated getters, setters, and builders.